# Is typing an accented character and compositing it the same?

Tags: accents, input-encodings

Suppose that I have T1 as font encoding (and therefore I will have no copy, search and hyphenation problems, etc).
Is there any difference between typing, for example, `\^e` and `ê` in the output?
My pratical experiences tell me that I have no problem with copy&paste or searching, both seem to work in the same way.

--
EDIT:
'font' encoding where it read 'input' and typo correction
ty [@David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle)

Comment: No, in general there is no difference. ê is a command and is mapped to \^e. But naturally your document could redefine ê to do something different.

Comment: T1 is a font (not input) encoding, assuming you have latin1 or utf8 as input encoding, and T1 as font encoding, those inputs are equivalent.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you don't load `inputenc`, `ê` is not translated into `\^e` at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're confusing between input and output encoding.

An input encoding is selected with a line such as

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and this allows using accented letters in the LaTeX document, such as `ê`. The option used must reflect the encoding used for saving the file.

An output encoding is selected with

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

The two calls are not linked. All `inputenc` does is translating input such as `ê` into a lower level command, which is precisely `\^{e}`, by the way. It's a job for the output encoding transforming this “LaTeX Internal Character Representation” (LICR) into an instruction of the form “select the character in slot `0xEA` (decimal 234) in the current font”.

A main source for misunderstanding is the fact that if

1. the file encoding is Latin-1 (known also as ISO 8859-1) and
2. the output encoding is T1

a document such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
ê
\end{document}
```

seems to compile correctly. Tell it to your German friends: a big surprise is in stock for them when they try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Straße
\end{document}
```

that will be incorrectly typeset as “StraSSe”. This is because Latin-1 and T1 coincide in several slots, but not all of them.

German or not, both `ê` and `ß` will give unpredictable results if the file encoding is UTF-8 and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is not included in the preamble like in the example just above. Here's a document that witness it; save it as UTF-8 and compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
êß
\end{document}
```

Here's the output

[image]

### Final recommendation

Load both packages, if you intend to use accented letters. And, possibly, switch to UTF-8. You'll be ready for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, if you want to try them.

Comment: Refering to your last sentence: Do you think XeTeX and LuaTeX are worth mentioning?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina No, a document *without* `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` would. I added some words for clarifying the matter.

Comment: I said 'input' encoding instead of 'font'. It was a mistake, I already corrected it.  Thank you for the explanation, it is very clear, I understood everything except for the mention of XeLaTex and LuaLaTeX.  So, inputenc turns all 'ê' and '\^e' into '\{e}' (with utf8) and this means 'yes' to my question. Then fontenc selects the correct glyph for output. :-)